error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'checkpoint_iter_370000.pth'
I'm trying to run the Colab demo but keep getting this error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'checkpoint_iter_370000.pth'

after executing this cell:
net = PoseEstimationWithMobileNet()
checkpoint = torch.load('checkpoint_iter_370000.pth', map_location='cpu')
load_state(net, checkpoint)

get_rect(net.cuda(), [image_path], 512)

I have tried both with the default test image and also with my own images. I'm always executing the cells in order.
What could be wrong here?

You should see the error twice before coming here. The error clealy says that thier is no such file checkpoint_iter_370000.pth . Are you sure file exists? on the left side drop down you can see the file?. If so the colab path will be a little different try https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=XDg9OBaYqRMd or share us colab link if you think you dont have any propriatary information

It's looking for that file in the current directory, which is not necessarily the same directory as the python code.  You can use this code to display the current directory import os; print(os.getcwd())

If you're sure the file exists (somewhere) you can remove any ambiguity by using an absolute (rather than relative) path
